# Grab relative URL with elementIdAttribute in Nightwatch

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-selectors, attributes, nightwatch.js

I want to grab the 'href' attribute from a link exactly as is in the source code so that I can locate the same link on another page. I thought that elementIdAttribute would grab the attribute and allow me to use it in a CSS locator, but for some reason elementIdAttribute completes relative URLs and appends slashes to the ends of some.

Here is the code I'm using to grab the 'href' attribute from the links on a page:

```
browser.elements("css selector", "div.field-item.even a", function(link_array) {
  link_tot = link_array.value.length;

  //Fetch the url from each 'a' tag in the content
  for (var x = 0; x < link_tot; x++){
    browser.elementIdAttribute(link_array.value[x].ELEMENT, "href", function(links) {
      console.log(links.value);
      urls.push(links.value);
    });
  }
})
```

If the 'href' property is `href='node/16376'`, then the link my program ends up outputting is `https://www.website.com/node/16376`. I want it so that it only outputs "node/16376" without the full url being appended to it.

Is there any way to grab the 'href' attribute exactly as is (ie. relative URLs without extra slashes appended to them) so that it can be used in a CSS selector to find the same link on another page?

Comment: Thinking I might need a new approach; elementIdAttribute is not grabbing the 'href' attribute as-is. It's turning the URL into an absolute alias and I can't find a way around it.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just modify your result by using JavaScript String `replace()` Method :

```
urls.push(links.value.replace('https://www.website.com/',''));
```

Comment: I need to grab whatever the 'href' property is in order to use it in a CSS selector. If the href is equal to an absolute URL, I don't want to strip anything out. If it's equal to a relative URL, I don't want to add anything to it. I can't tinker with the string after I grab it because I have no idea what will be. I just want to grab it as it is and leave it untouched so I can use it to locate links on another page that are using the exact same href attribute.